# Adding addition buttons to jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialog box that I wish to add an additional button to dynamically when a condition is met.

I set the dialog box on page load as follows

```
$("#confirmT").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    open: function() {
        pullResources(cat, id);
        },
    autoResize:true,
    width: 800,
    modal: true,
    title: 'Select Resources',
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function() {$(this).dialog( "close" );}},
    close: function() {
        }
        });
```

Then when a condition is true I want it to add another button to allow the user to add something to the database. This is what I have so far (from the jQuery ui website but nothing happens. No errors are produced, just nothing.

```
if ($sub == 1)
{
?>
        <script type = 'javascript'>
        function addbuttons()
        {
            // Setter
            $( "#confirmT" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", 
            [
                {
                    text: "Ok",
                    click: function() {
                            //do something
                    }
                }
            ]
            );

            } 
            addbuttons();</script>
            <?php
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try and create this portion of your app inside jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/uvep1fnc/

Add the button initially and based on the condition just call out the javascript function to hide the button.

**JS:-**

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [{
            text: "Delete all items",
            class: "aditya",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }]
    });

    function foo() {
        $("#dialog-confirm").closest(".ui-dialog").find(".aditya").hide();
    }

    foo();
});
```